# Node.js - Socket.io only accessible through localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

When I run my Node.js script, I can only access it by using localhost:8083, while using the machine's IP address from another device results in a "This site cannot be reached". I am using the following Node.js **server script**:

```
var app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    ent = require('ent'), // Blocks HTML characters (security equivalent to htmlentities in PHP)
    fs = require('fs');

// Loading the page index.html
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket, username) {
    // When the username is received it’s stored as a session variable and informs the other people
    socket.on('new_client', function(username) {
        username = ent.encode(username);
        socket.username = username;
        socket.broadcast.emit('new_client', username);(err) {});
    });

    // When a message is received, the client’s username is retrieved and sent to the other people
    socket.on('message', function (message) {
        message = ent.encode(message);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', {username: socket.username, message: message});
    }); 
});
console.log('Chat Socket.io running on port 8083');
server.listen(8083);
```

Here is the **client script**:

```
<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" > </script>
<script src="/socket.io / socket.io.js "></script>
<script>
    // Connecting to socket.io
    var socket = io.connect("10.254.17.115:8083");

    // The username is requested, sent to the server and displayed in the title
    var username = prompt('What\'s your username?');
    socket.emit('new_client', username);
    document.title = username + ' - ' + document.title;

    // When a message is received it's inserted in the page
    socket.on('message', function(data) {insertMessage(data.username, data.message)})

    // When a new client connects, the information is displayed
    socket.on('new_client', function(username) {
    $('#chat_zone').prepend(
        '<p><audio class="background" autoplay><source src="new-user.mp3" type="audio/wav"></audio><em>' + username + ' has joined the chat!</em></p>');
    })

    // When the form is sent, the message is sent and displayed on the page
    $('#chat_form').submit(function() {
        var message = $('#message').val();
        socket.emit('message', message); // Sends the message to the others
        insertMessage(username, message); // Also displays the message on our page
        $('#message').val('').focus(); // Empties the chat form and puts the focus back on it
        return false; // Blocks 'classic' sending of the form
    });

    // Adds a message to the page
    function insertMessage(username, message) {
        $('#chat_zone').prepend('<p><strong>' + username + '</strong> ' + message + '</p>');
    } 
</script>
```

**Edit:** Revised ports but they were not the issue. When I changed the `var socket = io.connect` to `io()` it worked.

Comment: Does the machine running the Socket.IO server allow incoming connections on that port? Perhaps the firewall is blocking those requests.

Comment: Wait, why is your client script trying to connect to port 8081 if the server is running on 8083?

Comment: `<script src="/socket.io / socket.io.js "></script>` with spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `connect` on the client side, when the client is served `socket.io.js`, it will attempt to connect automatically to the server from which the file was served, with a call to `io();`

Edit:

```
var socket = io();
```

Once the client has been served the socket.io.js, this is all you need to call. `socket` will be your socket object that is connected to the server, in this example.

Take a look at [this](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) simple example. You can see that in their client side examples, they only do `var socket = io();` to connect back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue with your server (and/or network) firewall, not with node.  Any time that you need to use a new port on your server, you'll need to open up any firewalls to allow traffic to that port.

A good place to start would be to download a port scanning utility (e.g. [nmap](https://nmap.org/)) onto the client that is trying to connect.  Then point the utility to the server, to see what ports are open.

Once you can confirm that it's a port issue, work on opening up that port on the machine's firewall.  After that, if you still cannot contact the machine, then a network firewall might be preventing the traffic from reaching the server.

If you still can't figure it out, you'll want to get some advice from a networking expert (not my area of expertise), so consider posting a question under [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).  Also, consider adding some error handling to the above code; it might help you to track down what exactly the problem is, if not a firewall issue.

Hope that helps,
~ Nate

Answer (score 1):

Client and server ports should match (8081 and 8083 dont) :)